Getting the Expression Tree of the Body of a Function in Julia
Is there a function or macro in Julia (or in package) that given a function returns the expression object (Expr) representing its body; or, in other words, returns the expression used in its definition?
For example, suppose a function foo is defined somewhere as
function foo(x, y)
    z = 2 * x
    return z + y
end

Then, supposing said function is called definition, calling definition(foo) should return the expression
quote
    z = 2 * x
    z + y
end

This should also in principle work for anonymous functions. The return value of definition(x -> 2 + x) should be the expression
:(2 + x)

I have been only able to find macros such as @code_lowered and @code_typed that get the code at LLVM Internal Representation, or native machine code level, but none at the expression level.

Are you looking for something like code_lowered(foo), code_typed(foo) (without @) or Base.uncompressed_ast(methods(foo).ms[1]).code ?

Maybe you mean Method rather than Function.  For example, methods(first) shows 24 methods for the generic function first.  Each presumably has a different definition.

@user9712582 Yes, you are right. How does one get a given function method from a function, so the examples can be corrected?

You can kinda get there with (@code_lowered foo(1,2)).code or (@code_typed foo(1,2))[1].code

"How does one get a given method from a function...?"  methods(foo)[1] will return the method if there is only one.  The macro @which finds the method given a function call expression, such as @which(first("ABCDEFG", 3)).  The function which finds a method given a tuple of argument type(s), such as which(first, (AbstractString, Integer)).

@GKi I looked at the code_lowered function, and indeed it gives what I am looking for. I had tried it before, and mistakenly thought the output was LLVM IR. If you write up an answer, I'll accept it to give you credit for helping me.

You could try code_lowered, code_typed (without @) or Base.uncompressed_ast(methods(foo).ms[1]).code.
function foo(x, y)
    z = 2 * x
    return z + y
end

code_lowered(foo)
#1-element Vector{Core.CodeInfo}:
# CodeInfo(
#1 ─      z = 2 * x
#│   %2 = z + y
#└──      return %2
#)

code_typed(foo)
#1-element Vector{Any}:
# CodeInfo(
#1 ─ %1 = (2 * x)::Any
#│   %2 = (%1 + y)::Any
#└──      return %2
#) => Any

Base.uncompressed_ast(methods(foo).ms[1]).code
#3-element Vector{Any}:
# :(_4 = 2 * _2)
# :(_4 + _3)
# :(return %2)

code_lowered(x -> 2 + x)
#1-element Vector{Core.CodeInfo}:
# CodeInfo(
#1 ─ %1 = 2 + x
#└──      return %1
#)

code_typed(x -> 2 + x)
#1-element Vector{Any}:
# CodeInfo(
#1 ─ %1 = (2 + x)::Any
#└──      return %1
#) => Any

Base.uncompressed_ast(methods(x -> 2 + x).ms[1]).code
#2-element Vector{Any}:
# :(2 + _2)
# :(return %1)

